# want to know if a table exists or not

Tags: android, sqlite

i have a table MY_DATABASE_TABLE .. but i want to know if it exists or not

```
public boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(MY_DATABASE_NAME, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
            checkDB.close();
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            // database doesn't exist yet.
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }
```

the above code didn't  worked and always returned false

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? If the database itself exists (as the code tries to do) - or if a table in the database exists as the subjects says?

Comment: Your code is correct, the problem should be your path, sorry that you mark the other answer as correct. Very poor solution BTW

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT() FROM sqlite_master WHERE name ='NAME_OF_YOUR_TABLE';
```

Comment: Easiest and bad as well

Comment: What is `sqlite_master` in your answer? May be i was wrong, it should be the name of the table and `WHERE name ='NAME_OF_YOUR_TABLE'` here `name` will be the column name and `'NAME_OF_YOUR_TABLE'` this will be value of  `name` column.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you're not checking if a table exists. You're opening a database.
Check these:
http://notes.theorbis.net/2008/12/check-if-datablase-table-exists.html
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/ffbe5bcdfbf5acaa